# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS install on new AMD PC, Nvidia Graphics do not work

Tags: boot

So i just built my new AMD PC, and was able to install Windows using a USB stick just fine.
Specs are Ryzen 3600, B550M mobo, Nvidia 1660 super GPU

Windows is running just fine, ran games, so GPU is working, its not broken or anything.
However Ubuntu (20.04 Desktop LTS) is unable to load properly, and i cant even get to initial graphical login screen or anything

I followed steps at https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

1. Created a USB stick using Rufus, for Desktop 20.04 LTS
2. Started graphics based install
3. Ensured Selected option to download updates during install Successfully
4. Completed the installation, got no errors during installation.

Post-install reboot i see a bunch of IRQ errors at load time, and then my screen shows no graphics/jumbled graphics like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9CX2.jpg

How can i get Ubuntu working properly on my new system?

Comment: Your grub shows 2 kernel versions, do either of them let you log in and get the desktop?

Comment: @darth_epoxy   I'm a real noob, i am trying to dual boot, Win10 installed first, Ubuntu second, i dont get a Grub, i have to force OS selection via F11 key :(

Comment: The third screenshot you posted here https://imgur.com/a/iRN2IZt is GRUB and that's what is normal when you boot. Do you need to press F11 to get that screen up? Problem is that windoze does not show as an option in your grub. Anyway, try all of the 4 Ubuntu options listed (up/down arrow then Enter) and see if you get to the login screen.